# How do I show that $f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R^2$ given by $f(x)=(x^3, |x^3|)$ is of class $C^2$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Hobbyist, working my way through Munkres's *Analysis on Manifolds*.  In one example (p. 196), author claims that $f:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R^2$ given by $$f(x)=(x^3, |x^3|)$$ is of class $C^2$.

Comment: The first component is clear, I suppose. So compute the first two derivatives of $x\mapsto \lvert x^3\rvert$, and see that they are continuous ($0$ is the only point where there's anything to show).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course $x^3$ is of class $C^\infty$. While $D^2 |x^3| = 6 |x|$ which is continuous. So $|x^3|$ is of class $C^2$.

Comment: Much obliged. I was substituting (x^6)^(1/2) for abs(x^3) to avoid dealing with the absolute value function, and getting lost in the algebra.  Thanks for your help.